# Import from one stub file into another

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Can I use a typed function definition from one stub file in another? E.g., I have my `__init__.pyi` and also `extractor.pyi`.

We want to reference some methods from `extractor.py`, so we keep compatibility and not redefine types.

In `extractor.pyi` I have:

```
def _func(arg: str) -> str: ...
```

Now I use in `__init__.pyi`:

```
from .extractor import _func
```

However, my linter is complaining.

Is it, in general, possible to import stubs from other `.pyi` files? If yes, how should I do it correctly?

Comment: What linter are you using? what is the error?

Comment: @DavidCulbreth, mypy,  
error: Module has no attribute "_func"  [attr-defined].  Overall Python code works, but only mypy complaints

Comment: sometimes the properties that are prefixed with a single underscore can be considered "private"-ish in python. you should make sure that `mypy` doesn't treat them that way. 
Optionally: rename the function to something else (like `func`) and see if you still have the error

Comment: It seems to me this might be exclusively related to imports. Please provide the project structure and check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) about relative imports. Moreover, the type annotation most likely have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: It could also be configuration issue in mypy standard paths. It might not be 'looking' for files in the path where your `extractor.py` is, which leads to it not understanding that it has a reference there.

Comment: Do you need to? I thought that `mypy`, if it needed any type information for something imported from `extractor.py`, would know to look in `extractor.pyi` automatically, without `__init__.pyi` having to know anything about `extractor.py` or `extractor.pyi`.

Comment: do not think it is related to imports, since in general code and all test work. Here is a commit: https://github.com/getsentry/responses/pull/397/commits/eaea4d5b2c3aa7e8d87e5e75d8a6b8d56b8ee9e1  Issue is on line 1310

Comment: since json_params_matcher is imported into the module for compatibility, it is not typed. However I typed it in parent file. But linter complains. Thus, I am not sure that what I do is a good practice